# Change contrast with slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I want centralise contrast theme with change according to slider value.

I want do as like

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: i have not try till now. i have no idea how to start code.

Comment: I tried this code but it does not reflects.
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                textScaleFactor: state.changedValue,
                boldText: state.boldText,
                //platformBrightness: Brightness.dark
                //highContrast: true,
                //invertColors: true
            ),